# Convert string value to date in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Trying converting the value **vr 27.03.2020** to a Date object

```
<script>
  let date = new Date("vr 27.03.2020");
  console.log(date);
</script>
```

Result:
**Invalid Date**

What is the best way convert the value to a Date object?

PS: **vr** is abbreviation from dutch *vrijdag* (=friday)

Comment: I'd say use a standard string representation

Comment: Get the digits, say using *match* or a *substring*, then pass them to the Date constructor. Remember to subtract 1 from the month. ;-)

Comment: You might also take a look at [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for all the answers. Do reseatch and i found when change the value to **vr 2020.03.27** then the result is: **Fri Mar 27 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Midden-Europese standaardtijd)** . This works correct, only, how change to this date-format (yy/mm/dd) in JS?